# Not able to display the clicked image

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i have few images that i am displaying in gridview. what i want is when i click that image it should be displayed in full screen. i have also put viewpager to have sliding functionality. the problem that i am having is when i click on an image the first image is displayed(not that one).

he is my main activity

```
public class Ppdtsample extends Activity {
GridView grid;

 static int[] imageId = { R.drawable.ppdt1, R.drawable.ppdt2,
        R.drawable.ppdt3, R.drawable.ppdt4, R.drawable.ppdt5,
        R.drawable.ppdt6, R.drawable.ppdt7, };

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ppdtsamples);

        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(Ppdtsample.this, imageId);
       grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                            // passing array index
                            i.putExtra("id", position);

                            startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

this is my activity to display in full screen with sliding functionality:

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {






@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
  int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    // passing array index

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);


    viewPager.setBackgroundResource(0);





    SlideImage adapter = new SlideImage(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

and this is my class for viewpager

```
public class SlideImage extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;


private int[] GalImages = { R.drawable.ppdt1, R.drawable.ppdt2,
        R.drawable.ppdt3, R.drawable.ppdt4, R.drawable.ppdt5,
        R.drawable.ppdt6, R.drawable.ppdt7, };


SlideImage(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
 }
```

it is displaying the first image and not the image i click because i am not able to pass the 'position' of the clicked image. it is taking the position from this method in SlideImage.class

```
Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
```

which is the first position. i want to pass the position from fullImageActivity.class to the position in this line

```
imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
```

which is on SlideshowActivity.

This may look complicated but i just want to pass the value of position from FullImageActivity.class to SlideImage.class. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ppdtsample` looks strange.Here I tried to modify your `Ppdtsample` class,which worked for me:

```
public class Ppdtsample extends Activity {
GridView grid;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of SlideImage Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new SlideImage(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullImageActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And the reason you can't pass the id is because you set the wrong adapter in `Ppdtsample`.It should be `SlideImage` in you code, not `ImageAdapter`.